# Finding the Euclidean distance between the vectors of matrix a, and vector b

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectors

Here is the problem,

> Given a 2D numpy array 'a' of sizes  n×m  and a 1D numpy array 'b' of
> size m. You need to find the distance(Euclidean) of the 'b' vector
> from the rows of the 'a' matrix. Fill the results in the numpy array.
> Follow up: Could you solve it without loops?

```
a = np.array([[1, 1],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 3],
              [4, 5]])
b = np.array([1, 1])
print(dist(a, b))
>>[0,1,2,5]
```

And here is my solution

```
import math


def dist(a, b):
    distances = []
    for i in a:
        distances.append(math.sqrt((i[0] - b[0]) ** 2 + (i[1] - b[1]) ** 2))
    return distances


a = np.array([[1, 1],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 3],
              [4, 5]])
print(dist(a, [1, 1]))
```

I wonder how can this be solved more elegant, and how the additional task can be implemented.

Comment: Use a combination of [array broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/theory.broadcasting.html?highlight=broadcast#array-broadcasting-in-numpy) and [universal functions](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/ufuncs.html#universal-functions-ufunc) to eliminate the loop. Also take a look at `numpy.linalg.norm()`

Comment: Yeah, I've already found out about that method, however, thank you!